# Passing Itemgroup between msbuild project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, tfs, msbuild, release-management

How can i pass an itemgroup between msbuild project using MSbuild task. I have an Msbuild task as given below

```
<Target Name ="test">
    <MSBuild Projects="New.proj" Targets="mytarget"
            Properties="Itemproperty=@(Item->'%(FullPath)')">
    </MSBuild>
</Target>
```

Where 'Item' is the itemgroup.But iam getting an error as below.

```
 error MSB4012: The expression "Itemproperty=@(Item->'%(FullPath)')" cannot be used in   this context. Item lists cannot beconcatenated with other strings where an item list is     expected. Use a semicolonto separate multiple item lists.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you "flatten" it into a big long (single) string?

example:

```
   <PropertyGroup>
        <MySuperLongString>@(MyIncludeFiles->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;')</MySuperLongString>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

Here are some more "options"

```
<Message Text="The below items are good when you need to feed command line tools, like the console NUnit exe.  Quotes around the filenames help with paths that have spaces in them. "/>
<Message Text="I found this method initially from : http://pscross.com/Blog/post/2009/02/22/MSBuild-reminders.aspx       Thanks Pscross! "/>
<Message Text="   "/>
<Message Text="   "/>



<Message Text="Flat list, each file surrounded by quotes, with semi colon delimiter: "/>
<Message Text="          @(MyIncludeFiles->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;')"/>
<Message Text="   "/>
<Message Text="   "/>



<Message Text="Flat list, each file surrounded by quotes, no comma (space delimiter): "/>
<Message Text="          @(MyIncludeFiles->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;' , ' ')"/>
<Message Text="   "/>
<Message Text="   "/>


<Message Text="Flat list, each file surrounded by quotes, with comma delimiter: "/>
<Message Text="          @(MyIncludeFiles->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;' , ',')"/>
<Message Text="   "/>
<Message Text="   "/>





<Message Text="List of files using special characters (carriage return)"/>
<Message Text="@(MyIncludeFiles->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;' , '%0D%0A')"/>
<Message Text="   "/>
<Message Text="   "/>
```

Full example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="AllTargetsWrapper" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <Target Name="AllTargetsWrapper">
        <CallTarget Targets="FunWithFilesTask" />
    </Target>


    <PropertyGroup>
        <WorkingCheckout>.</WorkingCheckout>
    </PropertyGroup>


                <!--    =====================================================                      -->

                <!--

              See:
              http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx

            *Identity    Value for the item specified in the Include attribute.
            *Filename   Filename for this item, not including the extension.
            *Extension  File extension for this item.
            *FullPath   Full path of this item including the filename.
            *RelativeDir    Path to this item relative to the current working directory.
            *RootDir    Root directory to which this item belongs.
            RecursiveDir    Used for items that were created using wildcards. This would be the directory that replaces the wildcard(s) statements that determine the directory.
            *Directory  The directory of this item.
            AccessedTime    Last time this item was accessed.
            CreatedTime     Time the item was created.
            ModifiedTime    Time this item was modified.   
              -->


    <Target Name="FunWithFilesTask">


        <ItemGroup>
            <MyExcludeFiles Include="$(WorkingCheckout)\**\*.doesnotexist" />
        </ItemGroup>

        <ItemGroup>
            <MyIncludeFiles Include="$(WorkingCheckout)\**\*.*" Exclude="@(MyExcludeFiles)" />
        </ItemGroup>  



        <PropertyGroup>
            <MySuperLongString>@(MyIncludeFiles->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;')</MySuperLongString>
    </PropertyGroup>  

    <Message Text="MySuperLongString=$(MySuperLongString)"/>
    <Message Text="   "/>
    <Message Text="   "/>


    <Message Text="The below items are good when you need to feed command line tools, like the console NUnit exe.  Quotes around the filenames help with paths that have spaces in them. "/>
    <Message Text="I found this method initially from : http://pscross.com/Blog/post/2009/02/22/MSBuild-reminders.aspx       Thanks Pscross! "/>
    <Message Text="   "/>
    <Message Text="   "/>



    <Message Text="Flat list, each file surrounded by quotes, with semi colon delimiter: "/>
    <Message Text="          @(MyIncludeFiles->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;')"/>
    <Message Text="   "/>
    <Message Text="   "/>



    <Message Text="Flat list, each file surrounded by quotes, no comma (space delimiter): "/>
    <Message Text="          @(MyIncludeFiles->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;' , ' ')"/>
    <Message Text="   "/>
    <Message Text="   "/>


    <Message Text="Flat list, each file surrounded by quotes, with comma delimiter: "/>
    <Message Text="          @(MyIncludeFiles->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;' , ',')"/>
    <Message Text="   "/>
    <Message Text="   "/>


    <Message Text="List of files using special characters (carriage return)"/>
    <Message Text="@(MyIncludeFiles->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;' , '%0D%0A')"/>
    <Message Text="   "/>
    <Message Text="   "/>



</Target>


</Project>
```

Comment: but how can i pass this item to the other msbuild project.Can't simply pass the properties because i have to do a sequence of tasks for each item.Next item will be processed only after completing these sequence of tasks.

Comment: Then "you can't"....It's not wired like that.  But if someone knows how, then I'll learn something too.  But I'm fairly certain you can't do that.